# Django-crontab is not working on in linux ec2 instance

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, cron, django-cron

I'm trying to set up cron jobs in my django application on a ec2 instance(linux). Everything is working fine, I tried

`python3 manage.py cron add`

`python3 manage.py cron show`

`python3 manage.py cron remove`

everything works just fine

But when I start the apache server, and load the page, I'm getting 500. From the error logs I found that `django_crontab` module was not found. But it's still there and I've installed it in the virtual environment too (I've double checked with pip3 freeze). I also tried `sudo service cron start` which didn't show me anything and didn't make any difference. What could be the possible issue here?

Comment: is this same environment mod_wsgi is using, did you try it on different environment(locally)

Comment: I tried running in my local machine with and without environment, it works fine. But it is not working only on ec2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atleast I found the answer myslef. Freezing the `pip3` modules and installing it in the server environment solved my issue. `MODULE_IMPORT ERROR` can be rectified by this method even if your module is not visible when installed manualy using `pip3 install module-name`. I hope this works for others!